# Datetime saying my time format is wrong but it isn't

Tags: python

My date time conversion was working and now I am getting this error when I haven't changed anything..

```
time data '2019-04-14_27-35-34-859' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S-%f'
```

```
def get_milliseconds(time_stamp):
        utc_time = datetime.strptime(time_stamp,
                             '%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S-%f')
        milliseconds = (utc_time - datetime(1970, 1, 1)) // timedelta(milliseconds=1)
        print("milliseconds = " + str(milliseconds))
        return milliseconds
```

Answer (score 1):

Your value for `%H` is invalid - the hour can only be 00-23, not 24+ (which makes sense right, you don't have 27 hours in a day).

Unfortunately the error message isn't actually helpful, but if you exclude minutes/seconds/milliseconds from your string, a more helpful message arises:

```
>>> s = '2019-04-14_27'
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d_%H')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py", line 577, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 7
```

[Relevant documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).